# Validation of hasMany relation of unsaved objects

Tags: validation, grails, constraints, grails-domain-class

In a Grails 2.3.4 application I have a domain class representing relation between the author and articles. It contains three attributes:

- type id (representing author (1), viewer (3) and other types)
- member
- article

-

```
class Article {
  static hasMany = [ relations: ArticleRelation ]

  string title
}

class ArticleRelation {
  static belongsTo = [ article: Article ]

  int    type
  Member member
}
```

Some of the types semantically shall not allow to create more than one pair of type+author. For example:

- each article is allowed to have only one author

Other type+author don't have that restrictions. For example: viewer.

A condition was added to ArticleRelation to prevent the duplicates like this:

```
static constraints = {
  article validator: { val, obj ->
    if ((obj.type == 1) || (obj.type == 2)) {
      if (ArticleRelation.countByArticleAndType(val, obj.type) > 0) return ['myNotUniqueErrorKey']
    }
  }
}
```

However, in Grails 2.3 this validation does not prevent from adding duplicates to article relations like this:

```
def article = new Article(title: "Man on the Moon")
article.addToRelations(new ArticleRelation(type:1, member:me))
article.addToRelations(new ArticleRelation(type:1, member:you))

article.validate()
```

Validation does not fail as I expected. I assume that the it is because the objects were not yet saved.

Shall validation be somehow implemented in Article (as well)? If so, how?

Comment: Why don't you save entities before validation?

Comment: I agree with Pawel - save your `ArticleRelation`s first. Make sure everything is wrapped in a transaction (in a service) that can be rolled back if validation fails.